# Django ORM: Excluding Specific Record in Many-to-Many Relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I have a many-to-many relationship between two models Profile and Conversation like this:

```py
class Profile(models.Model):
    # ...

class Conversation(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name="conversations")
```

Now I want to select all the conversations that a specific profile is a member in it, I tried this which worked but I'm not sure if it's the right way:

```py
conversations = Conversation.objects.filter(members='<profile_pk>')
```

Also, I want to exclude that member's data from the result because I already have it, or should I exclude his data on the client side?

Comment: What do you mean with "exclude that member's data". This query will not fetch any member data, it only fetches conversations.

Comment: I mean to exclude the profile_pk that I filtered the conversations with from the conversation's members field result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, this is the right way, you can filter with:

```
conversations = Conversation.objects.filter(members=profile_pk)  # or
conversations = Conversation.objects.filter(members=profile_object)  # or
conversations = Conversation.objects.filter(members__id=profile_pk)
```

> Also, I want to exclude that member's data from the result because I already have it.

The query will *not* fetch member data, it will only fech `Conversation`s. If you then query `myconversation.members.all()`, you get all member data, including the one of the `Profile`.

If you want to exclude that `Profile` from the members when you fetch this, you can work with a `Prefetch` object:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

conversations = Conversation.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('members', Profile.objects.exclude(pk=profile_pk))
).filter(members=profile_pk)
```

The `Conversation`s will then not contain the item with *`profile_pk`* as item of the `Member`s.